# Rabbitmq Client stuck into loop golang

Tags: go, rabbitmq

Been having quite a problem lately, as I'm trying to watch events happening on my secrets, I modified my go scripts to instantiate RabbitMQ. Added an EventWatcher and a go routine in order to solve that. But then what's happening is that my client seems to be completely stuck after "RabbitMQ client connected"
"Init Channel"
"Change Channel fun"
logs, nothing is happening.

I interacted a go routine for the watching event part inside of another one, make sense since it's different threads.

Hopefully some of y'all can help.

func (rmq *Client) handleClientReconnect() {
defer rmq.secretWatcher.Close()

```
for {
    select {
    case event, ok := <-rmq.secretWatcher.Events:
        if !ok {
            return
        }
        if event.Has(fsnotify.Remove) || event.Has(fsnotify.Write) {
            ilog.Info(event.Name)
        }
    case err, ok := <-rmq.secretWatcher.Errors:
        if !ok {
            return
        }
        ilog.Errorf("Error in watcher: %v", err)
    case <-rmq.done:
        return
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have a program that connects to RabbitMQ to watch for events. You use channels and goroutines to listen to these events. However, it seems that the program is getting stuck after connecting to RabbitMQ, and nothing is happening.

The reason for this is that one of your goroutines, handleClientReconnect(), is blocking the main goroutine from proceeding. This is because the function is listening for events on a channel that is never closed.

To fix this issue, you need to make sure that the channel is closed when it's no longer needed. You can do this by adding a defer statement to the function, which will automatically close the channel when the function exits.

In addition, you should add a condition to the for loop in handleClientReconnect() that checks if the program is shutting down. If it is, then the function should exit. This will prevent the program from getting stuck and allow it to proceed as intended.

```golang
func (rmq *Client) handleClientReconnect() {
    defer rmq.secretWatcher.Close()

    for {
        select {
        case event, ok := <-rmq.secretWatcher.Events:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            if event.Has(fsnotify.Remove) || event.Has(fsnotify.Write) {
                ilog.Info(event.Name)
            }
        case err, ok := <-rmq.secretWatcher.Errors:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            ilog.Errorf("Error in watcher: %v", err)
        case <-rmq.done:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about that as well. Sadly, result is the same : stuck here after these logs           "RabbitMQ client connected"  "Init Channel" then "Change Channel func", so  no improvements :( Feels like it's stuck around the handleChannel…. but can't figure out why

Comment: I understand that you're having a problem with your Go script that is using RabbitMQ to watch events happening on your secrets. The script seems to be stuck after printing "RabbitMQ client connected", "Init Channel", and "Change Channel func" logs.

One possible solution is to check if there are any errors when initializing the channel and creating the connection to RabbitMQ. It's also important to make sure that the RabbitMQ server is running and that the necessary credentials are provided.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, please share your docker-compose file if you have one. This can help others reproduce the same problem locally and provide more specific solutions.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not able to give the file. But I am, if you're looking at the initchannel methods catching errors. Though nothing is getting outputted. Cannot figure out why. My client seems to be connected fine…. But thanks a lot for the help ! Much appreciated